# jQuery filtering select options does not work in Safari (but works in Chrome and FF)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a form with some dropdowns, and the first selected dropdown will serve to filter the second dropdown's choices (to limit them). The following code works just fine in FF and Chrome but will not work in Safari (version 11.1.2 at least):

```
if(~jQuery(this).attr('id').indexOf('5b0ad35592224') && ~jQuery(this).attr('id').indexOf(jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id'))) {
        var vallie = jQuery(this).val();
        var sub = jQuery('[id*="'+jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id')+'-field_5b0ad39f92225"]');
        console.log(sub);
        jQuery('option', sub).filter(function(){
            if (~jQuery(this).val().indexOf(vallie) || jQuery(this).val() === 'Choisir') {
                jQuery(this).show();
            } else {
                jQuery(this).hide();
            }
        });
      jQuery(sub).val('Choisir');  
    };
```

The odd thing is when I console log the values returned for `vallie` or `sub` or `jQuery(this).val().indexOf(vallie)` they are the same in all browsers. I am stumped as to why Safari does not filter the options in the second dropdown (it just shows all the options)

Comment: That's because hiding `<option>` is not supported cross browser. IE and Safari don't support it. Choices are disable/enable or remove/replace. Or use a `<select>` replacement script that has filtering feature

Comment: I have tried cloning the (dynamic) dropdown, then filtering (using remove for the un-needed options), but for some reason trying to show the newly cloned dropdown fails (even though I can log it and see that it had filtered correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @charlietfl for alerting me to the fact that hiding options is not universally supported. Here is the solution I ended up going with:

1. I separated my options into separate js objects
2. I then check the value from the first dropdown, and use that to get the correct menu object
3. I then empty the existing (full) menu, and then append the options from the appropriate object.

Here is the actual code:

```
if(~jQuery(this).attr('id').indexOf('5b0ad35592224') && ~jQuery(this).attr('id').indexOf(jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id'))) {
  var vallie = jQuery(this).val();
  var thismenu = menu_portes; // set default menu object
  if (vallie === 'Tiroir') {thismenu = menu_tiroirs } else if (vallie === 'Côté') {thismenu = menu_cotes }
  var $sub = jQuery('[id*="'+jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id')+'-field_5b0ad39f92225"]');

  $sub.empty(); // remove old options
  $sub.append(jQuery('<option>', { value: 'Choisir', text: 'Choisir'})); // add Choisir at top
  jQuery.each(thismenu, function(key,value) { // loop through my object options
    $sub.append(jQuery("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value)); //append options from my menu object
  });
  jQuery($sub).val('Choisir'); // set menu to Choisir 
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `.filter`, you should be return a boolean indicating whether or not to include the current item instead of using `.show()` and `.hide()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

Otherwise, use `.each` or `.map`