# Why is JQuery dropdown list filtering not working in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I've created an HTML and JS (JQuery) form with multiple dropdowns that filter the values from one to the next. So when brand1 is selected only products from brand1 are shown.

This works perfectly well in Chrome, but does nothing in Safari (with JS on in security settings).

Is there something else I need to do to make Safari happy?

[Here's the jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tbizzle/fswyctm9/7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#brand").on("change", function() {
    var selectbrand = $("#brand").val();
    $("#model option").attr("hidden", "hidden");
    $("#model option[data-for='" + selectbrand + "']").removeAttr("hidden");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brand">
  <option data-for="default">Select your brand</option>
  <option data-for="1">1</option>
  <option data-for="2">2</option>
  <option data-for="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="model">
  <option data-for="default">Select your model</option>
  <option data-for="1" value="1 Model 1">1 Model 1</option>
  <option data-for="1" value="1 Model 2">1 Model 2</option>
  <option data-for="2" value="2 Model 1">2 Model 1</option>
  <option data-for="2" value="2 Model 2">2 Model 2</option>
  <option data-for="3" value="3 Model 1">3 Model 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is "on load" which it should not be.

Comment: Also your second select is not resetting when changing the first select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note your fiddle is "on load" which will fail because you have `$(document).ready`

Update: [jQuery filtering select options does not work in Safari (but works in Chrome and FF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086851/jquery-filtering-select-options-does-not-work-in-safari-but-works-in-chrome-and)

Here is a better version.

```js
const models = {
  "brand1" : [ "1 Model 1", "1 Model 2" ],
  "brand2" : [ "2 Model 1", "2 Model 2" ],
  "brand3" : [ "3 Model 1" ]
}

$(function() {
  $("#brand").on("change", function() {
    var selectbrand = $("#brand").val(), domSel = $("#model")[0];
    domSel.selectedIndex=0;
    domSel.options.length=1;
    if (selectbrand) {
      $.each(models[selectbrand],function(_,model) {
        $("#model").append("<option value='"+model+"'>"+model+"</option>")
      });  
    }  
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brand">
  <option value="">Select your brand</option>
  <option value="brand1">Brand 1</option>
  <option value="brand2">Brand 2</option>
  <option value="brand3">Brand 3</option>
</select>

<select id="model">
  <option value="">Select your model</option>
</select>
```

Old code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#brand").on("change", function() {
    var selectbrand = $("#brand").val();
    $("#model")[0].selectedIndex=0;
    $("#model option").hide();
    $("#model option[data-for='" + selectbrand + "']").show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brand">
  <option data-for="default">Select your brand</option>
  <option data-for="1">1</option>
  <option data-for="2">2</option>
  <option data-for="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="model">
  <option data-for="default">Select your model</option>
  <option data-for="1" value="1 Model 1">1 Model 1</option>
  <option data-for="1" value="1 Model 2">1 Model 2</option>
  <option data-for="2" value="2 Model 1">2 Model 1</option>
  <option data-for="2" value="2 Model 2">2 Model 2</option>
  <option data-for="3" value="3 Model 1">3 Model 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tested your 'old code' in Safari and it doesn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/3m6xqLdf/). As far as I am aware there is no way to hide an option in Safari. You may have some luck with custom styling (`-webkit-appearance: none;`) and then making the option visibly hidden (maybe with `max-height:0` or similar) but I'm dubious.

Comment: Please see updated code (example 1)

Comment: Example 1 works for me in Safari 12

Answer (score 0):

Safari renders things differently and uses a UI overlay for dropdowns. You can't just hide them, but you can move them. Here I use jQuery to move the option to and from a hidden store:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#brand").on("change", function() {
    var selectbrand = $(this).val();
    $("#model option[data-for]").appendTo("#modelStore");
    $("#modelStore option[data-for='" + selectbrand + "']").appendTo("#model");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="brand">
  <option data-for="default">Select your brand</option>
  <option data-for="1">1</option>
  <option data-for="2">2</option>
  <option data-for="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="model">
  <option>Select your model</option>
</select>

<select id="modelStore" style="display:none;">
  <option data-for="1" value="1 Model 1">1 Model 1</option>
  <option data-for="1" value="1 Model 2">1 Model 2</option>
  <option data-for="2" value="2 Model 1">2 Model 1</option>
  <option data-for="2" value="2 Model 2">2 Model 2</option>
  <option data-for="3" value="3 Model 1">3 Model 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Interesting. I cannot test my code until I am home. Very curious if my code actually does work